# What is a "baling top"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Found it in Patrick Rothfuss's book "The Slow Regard for Silent Things." I tried googling it but came up with nothing.

> She already had straw here, and three bottles waited on a narrow ledge of stone along one wall. But looking at them, Auri frowned. There was a green one, a brown one, and a clear one. There was a wide wire **baling top**, a grey twisting lid, and a cork fat as a fist. They were all different shapes and sizes, but none of them were quite right.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know they were called this, but suspected it meant that type of bottle closure where the stopper is held in by a stiff wire arrangement that is over-centred and under tension. A bit of googling revealed this, for instance:https://freundcontainer.com/glass-bale-wire-bottles-with-swing-top-cap/